# How to uniquely merge two elements of a list in r while eliminating the others

Tags: r

I have a problem to be done in R:

I have a list which has elements that need to be matched and merged. For example, element one of the list should be matched then merged with element 25. I would like to take the vector in 25 and concatenate it with the vector in 1 and delete element 25. I will elaborate using the data below.

```
   > mydata=read.csv("mydata.csv",h=T)
   > mydata
            V1    V2      V3
      1      1   236    2457
      2      1   236  134567
      3      1  2457  134567
      4      2   136    1457
      5      2   136  234567
      6      2  1457  234567
      7      3   126  123457
      8      3   126    4567
      9      3  4567  123457
      10     4  1257   12346
       :     :    :      :
      90   136  1457  234567
       :     :    :      :
      108  236  2457  134567
       :     :    :      :
      121  567  1246   12357
      122 1236 12457   34567
      123 1245  3456   12367
      124 1247  3467   12356
      125 1257  3567   12346
```

Looking at the data above one will see that row 1 and 2 contain elements of row 108 and row 3 contain elements of row 1and  thus I desire to combine all rows 1,2,3 and 108 together, take the unique values and give them the name 1 while getting rid of the other three rows . Also rows 4,5,6 and 90 should be merged and given the name 2. How would I go about this? What is the best criteria to solve this?
Now I would love to do this for all the other elements in my data. Is there a way to go about it? Do not mind about the arrangement or the order of the resulting vectors. This is just a small example and the data is quite huge and needs to be cleaned up.

```
    dput(mydata)

    structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 
    15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 23, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 26, 
    27, 27, 27, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 36, 37, 37, 37, 45, 45, 45, 
    46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 67, 67, 67, 123, 
    124, 125, 126, 127, 134, 134, 134, 135, 135, 135, 136, 137, 137, 
    137, 145, 146, 146, 146, 147, 156, 156, 156, 157, 167, 167, 167, 
    234, 235, 236, 237, 245, 246, 247, 256, 257, 267, 345, 347, 357, 
    456, 467, 567, 1236, 1245, 1247, 1257), V2 = c(236, 236, 2457, 
    136, 136, 1457, 126, 126, 4567, 1257, 1257, 3567, 1247, 1247, 
    3467, 123, 123, 3457, 1245, 1245, 3456, 36, 36, 457, 26, 26, 
    14567, 257, 257, 2346, 247, 247, 2356, 23, 23, 13457, 245, 245, 
    2367, 13457, 157, 157, 1346, 147, 147, 1356, 14567, 145, 145, 
    1367, 567, 567, 1246, 467, 467, 1256, 457, 456, 456, 1267, 127, 
    127, 367, 357, 357, 1234, 125, 125, 356, 347, 347, 1235, 124, 
    124, 346, 345, 345, 1237, 3457, 346, 356, 4567, 367, 246, 246, 
    1567, 256, 256, 1467, 1457, 267, 267, 1456, 1367, 234, 234, 1357, 
    1356, 235, 235, 1347, 1346, 237, 237, 1345, 1357, 1347, 2457, 
    1345, 2367, 1567, 2356, 1467, 2346, 1456, 1237, 1235, 1234, 1267, 
    1256, 1246, 12457, 3456, 3467, 3567), V3 = c(2457, 134567, 134567, 
    1457, 234567, 234567, 123457, 4567, 123457, 12346, 3567, 12346, 
    12356, 3467, 12356, 124567, 3457, 124567, 12367, 3456, 12367, 
    457, 1234567, 1234567, 23457, 14567, 23457, 2346, 13567, 13567, 
    2356, 13467, 13467, 24567, 13457, 24567, 2367, 13456, 13456, 
    24567, 1346, 23567, 23567, 1356, 23467, 23467, 23457, 1367, 23456, 
    23456, 1246, 12357, 12357, 1256, 12347, 12347, 1234567, 1267, 
    12345, 12345, 123456, 367, 123456, 1234, 12567, 12567, 123467, 
    356, 123467, 1235, 12467, 12467, 123567, 346, 123567, 1237, 12456, 
    12456, 124567, 123567, 123467, 123457, 123456, 2357, 1567, 2357, 
    2347, 1467, 2347, 234567, 2345, 1456, 2345, 23456, 2567, 1357, 
    2567, 23467, 2467, 1347, 2467, 23567, 2456, 1345, 2456, 2567, 
    2467, 134567, 2456, 13456, 2357, 13467, 2347, 13567, 2345, 12456, 
    12467, 12567, 12345, 12347, 12357, 34567, 12367, 12356, 12346
    )), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -125L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please also take into consideration that there may be may rows related with a single element. The rows may or may not be duplicated. Thank you
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Tip: if you add the output of `dput(mydata)` to your question, others will be able to load the data by copy pasting it. This will increase the chance someone will answer your question.

Comment: Maybe `unique(t(apply(cbind(rownames(mydata), mydata), 1, sort)))`

Comment: Thank you. I never knew that. Will do exactly that. Am so grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your data is as follows:

```
> dput(dat)

structure(list(ABCDD = c("ABBCCD", "ABBCDD", "ABCCDD", "ABC", 
"ABCDDE", "ABCCD", "ACCD", "ABBCD", "ABBD", "ABBCC", "ABBCCDD", 
"ABBCCDEE", "ABBCCDE", "ABBCCDD", "ABBDD", "ABBC", "ABBCD", "ABBCDDE", 
"ABBCDDEE", "ABCC", "ABCCD", "ABCCDDE", "ABCCDDEE", "ABCE", "ABCEE"
), AABBCCD = c("BCDD", "ACDD", "ABDD", "ABCD", "ABCDDEE", "CDD", 
"BCCD", "BDD", "BCCDD", "BCD", "BC", "BCDDEE", "BCDDE", "ADD", 
"ACCDD", "ACD", "AC", "ACDDEE", "ACDDE", "ABD", "AB", "ABDDEE", 
"ABDDE", "ABCDEE", "ABCDE"), ABBCCE = c("ABCEE", "ACCE", "ABBE", 
"ABBCCDE", "ABBCCEE", "ACEE", "ABBCEE", "ABEE", "ABCCEE", "ABCDDEE", 
"ABCDEE", "ABCE", "ABC", "AE", "ACE", "ACCDE", "ACCDDE", "ACCEE", 
"ACC", "ABBDE", "ABBDDE", "ABBEE", "ABB", "ABBCCDEE", "ABBCCD"
), AABCEE = c("BCEE", "ABCCE", "ABBCE", "ABBCCDDE", "ABBCC", 
"BCCE", "CEE", "BCCEE", "BEE", "BCDEE", "BCDDEE", "BC", "BCE", 
"ABCE", "ABE", "ABCCDDE", "ABCCDE", "ABCC", "ABCCEE", "ABBCDDE", 
"ABBCDE", "ABBC", "ABBCEE", "ABBCCDD", "ABBCCDDEE"), ADEE = c("ADDE", 
"ABDEE", "ACDEE", "ADDEE", "AD", "ABBDDE", "ABDDE", "ACCDDE", 
"ACDDE", "ADE", "AE", "ADD", "ADDEE", "ABCDEE", "ABCCDEE", "ABDDEE", 
"ABEE", "ABD", "ABDE", "ACDDEE", "ACEE", "ACD", "ACDE", "ADD", 
"ADDE"), AADDE = c("DEE", "ABBDEE", "ACCDEE", "AEE", "ADE", "BDDE", 
"BDEE", "CDDE", "CDEE", "E", "DE", "DE", "D", "ABBCCDEE", "ABBCDEE", 
"ABBEE", "ABBDDEE", "ABBDE", "ABBD", "ACCEE", "ACCDDEE", "ACCDE", 
"ACCD", "AE", "A"), BCDE = c("ABCDE", "BCCDDEE", "BCCDE", "BCDDE", 
"BCDEE", "ABBCDE", "ACDE", "ABCCDE", "ABDE", "ABCDDE", "ABCE", 
"ABCDEE", "ABCD", "BCDDEE", "BDDEE", "BCCDEE", "BCCEE", "BCCDDE", 
"BCCDD", "BCCDDE", "BCCE", "BCCDEE", "BCCD", "BCDDEE", "BCDD"
), BBCCDDE = c("ABBCCDDEE", "CDE", "BDE", "BCE", "BCD", "ACCDDEE", 
"ABCCDDEE", "ABBDDEE", "ABBCDDEE", "ABBCCEE", "ABBCCDEE", "ABBCCDD", 
"ABBCCDDE", "DE", "CDDEE", "CE", "CDDE", "CD", "CDEE", "BE", 
"BDDE", "BD", "BDEE", "BC", "BCEE")), .Names = c("ABCDD", "AABBCCD", 
"ABBCCE", "AABCEE", "ADEE", "AADDE", "BCDE", "BBCCDDE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "AB", "ABB", "AC", "ACC", "AD", "ADD", "AE", 
"AEE", "BC", "BCC", "BD", "BDD", "BE", "BEE", "CD", "CDD", "CE", 
"CEE", "DE", "DEE"))
```

What I assume is that row names are meaningful, but column names are not. Therefore, I suggest:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% rownames_to_column() %>%           # convert row names to separate column,
 t() %>% as_data_frame() %>% as.list() %>% # split your data frame by row into a list,
 map(sort) %>%                             # sort each element of a list,
 do.call(rbind, .) %>% as_data_frame() %>% # reassemble the list into the data frame (by row), and  
 distinct()                                # eliminate duplicates
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am so grateful I just guess I never thought of it when asking the question. This code only works when I have duplicates. What of when my rows have no duplicates? When one row is distinct from the other but contain that one element that is  also contained in the other row too making the two to be equal?. How will I go about that?. Thank you..

Comment: Could you think about restating your original question: do you want each row to contain only unique values (i.e. if any two rows contain at least one overlapping element they should be merged)? It might be that the problem is better solved with lists, not data frames

Comment: Thank you. I guess I will have to edit it. Lemme do exactly that. I will have to use a different set of data. Thank you